# Android App is logged in even app is re-installed

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have an Android app where I have at the start of the app.

There is one weird thing happening with my app.

Even I delete app and re-install, the app takes last logged in data and show me that I am already logged in.

Below are the steps.

1. Login to app as testuser
2. Delete app
3. Install app again
4. Actually it should ask me for login, however it shows that I am already logged in with testuser.

OS that I have on Android is 7.0 on S6 Edge phone.

**Note** : I check on S4 and all is fine. It ask me to login on each re-install.

---

Comment: how you check user is login ?

Comment: **`android:allowBackup="false"`** in manifest file

Comment: @y.feizi : user id is saved in shared preference... but when I re-install, it should be 0 (which is default)

Comment: @Prem : can you explain how that will help? I have true as of now... its works fine for S4

Comment: @FahimParkar https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apps that target Android 6.0 (API level 23) or higher automatically participate in Auto Backup. This is because the `android:allowBackup` attribute, which enables/disables backup, defaults to true if omitted. To avoid confusion, we recommend you explicitly set the attribute in the `<application>` element of your `AndroidManifest.xml.`

```
<application ...
    android:allowBackup="false">
</application>
```

**Files that are backed up**

By default, Auto Backup includes files in most of the directories that are assigned to your app by the system:

- `Shared preferences` files.
- `Files` in the directory returned by `getFilesDir()`.
- `Files` in the directory returned by `getDatabasePath(String)`, which also includes files created with the `SQLiteOpenHelper` class.
- `Files` in directories created with `getDir(String, int)`.
- `Files` on external storage in the directory returned by `getExternalFilesDir(String).`

for more information read [Auto Backup for Apps](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup.html)

or when you logout Try to delete in manually like this

```
File preferenceFile = new File("/data/data/"+ getPackageName()+ "/shared_prefs/");
File[] listFiles = preferenceFile.listFiles();
for (File file : listFiles) {
    file.delete();
}
```

Comment: for me 6.0 is fine, but 7.0 is not fine... however you said this is for 6.0 and above... am I missing anything?

Comment: @FahimParkar may issue with 7.0 did you try **android:allowBackup="false"**

Comment: this helped it solved the issue only few people were having this issue on their devices that's why it was difficult to solve.